# Unit Testing a 'SetDefaults()' method

Tags: unit-testing

I am in the process of learning to unit test.  I have a 'domain object' that doesn't do much apart from hold state (i.e. `Employee` without any business logic).  It has a method `SetDefaults()` which just fills its state with reasonable values.  A simple method.

But when I go to unit test this method all I can think of is to run the method then check that every field is what it should be.  Like (in `C#`):

```
        [TestMethod()]
    public void SetDefaultsTest()
    {
        Employee target = new Employee();

        employee.SetDefaults();

        Assert.AreEqual(employee.Name, "New Employee");
        Assert.AreEqual(employee.Age, 30);
        // etc.
    }
```

It feels wrong to duplicate the entire functionality of SetDefaults() within my test.  Should I just leave this method untested?  The problem is that I'd like a test to ensure that when new properties are added to the class they are also added to the SetDefaults() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trivial getters and setters sometimes don't have unit tests written for them. If that's all that SetDefaults() does, it probably won't hurt to skip it.

One thing you would want to consider testing, though, is that none of the set properties of the `employee` instance are null after calling `SetDefaults()`:

```
var nonNullProperties = new object[] { employee.Name, employee.Age, ... };
foreach (var property in nonNullProperties)
  Assert.IsNotNull(property);
```

This makes sense, since you really just care that they *are* set to some default value, and not so much that they're a *specific* value.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what value you get out of that test.  Don't test just for the sake of testing.  However, if those defaults are important to be correct, and not change, then go right ahead.

A lot of testing involves deciding "Hey, is this going to make my job easier in the long run?"  Are these defaults changing all the time, or are they constant?  Are the defaults very complicated, or are they a handful of strings and numbers?  How important is it to the customer that these defaults are correct?  How important is it to the other developers that the defaults are correct?

The test could do a million things, but if it doesn't add some value to someone who cares about it, then don't worry about it.  If you've been asked to automate testing of 100% of all your code, perhaps reading up and discussing some of the ideas presented in the following blogs might benefit your team:

http://blog.jayfields.com/2009/02/thoughts-on-developer-testing.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163665.aspx

Otherwise, if it doesn't add much value or constantly breaks, I'd say go ahead and leave it out.

Comment: Thanks, the Jay Fields link is packed full of interesting information.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a pretty reasonable unit test to me. You are providing a simple test that checks the results of calling that method. It doesn't help you with any new properties though, as the existing test would still pass. Perhaps you could use Reflection to iterate over all the properties of the object and check they are non-null?

Also `SetDefaults()` seems like a slightly odd method. Why not just initialise a new `Employee` to those values to start with? That way there is no risk that another coder will create an `Employee` and forget to call `SetDefaults()`.

Comment: It does get called in the constructor but is also left as a public method in case it needs to be called on an existing object.

Comment: Well (depending how thorough you need to be) you probably want one test that checks the default values immideiately after an Employee is created and a second test that creates an employee, sets all the values to non-default, then calls SetDefaults() and checks they are all properly reset.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Would it be ok to call the first test method from the second test, as a form of refactoring?  I feels correct but I am still unsure about how much to refactor the test code.

Comment: Generally speaking I try to avoid refactoring unit tests too much, Unit tests should be kept as straightforward and simple as possible, even if that means repeating code. This allows maintenance programmers to very quickly see why a test has failed.